# Using Groovy with Multiple TestNG Parameters

Tags: groovy, testng

I am trying to pass in multiple parameters into a TestNG annotated method where my class is written in Groovy.  I understand the correct formats for multiple TestNG parameters are the following:

```
@Parameters({"category", "exampleDesc"})           //option 1
@Parameters(value = {"category", "exampleDesc"})   //option 2
```

However, as I'm using Groovy, I see the following error:

> ';', '}' or new line expected

If I follow either option 1 or 2 in the error I see

> Cannot assigned 'Class' to 'String[]'.

This problem does not exist when using Java. Is there a way to pass in multiple parameters to TestNG annotated methods with Groovy? For those curious, I'm using a @DataProvider in another area of the code.

Thank you in advance! Here's a snitbit of code:

```
public class test {
     @BeforeClass
     @Parameters({"A", "B"})
     public def before(A, B) { //code here } 
}
```

Comment: Not that it should matter but I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.5

Comment: Have you tried the Groovy list format of `@Parameters(["category", "exampleDesc"])` ?

Comment: I had not but that did solve the issue.  Can you respond so I can accept your answer @tim_yates ??  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Groovy to make a list or array of Strings, you need to use `[]` instead of `{}`, so the annotation becomes:

```
@Parameters(["category", "exampleDesc"])
```